# rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant UpdateDateOnReservations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

This migration is from a while ago, it never caused a problem until now. Im not sure what i'm doing wrong. Here is the whole error message:

```
Hiras-MacBook-Pro:seatyourself hirakazmi$ 
  be rake db:migrate rake aborted!

  NameError: uninitialized constant UpdateDateOnReservations
  /Users/hirakazmi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
  /Users/hirakazmi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'

  NameError: uninitialized constant UpdateDateOnReservations
  /Users/hirakazmi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
  /Users/hirakazmi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'

  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Hiras-MacBook-Pro:seatyourself hirakazmi$
```

Comment: Can you check your migration folder for a file named: `update_date_on_reservations[timestams].rb` and post the content

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a rails migration file named `db/migrations/20160000000000_update_date_on_reservations.rb`. Inside that file, your class name does not match the file name.

That migration file should should define the class like:

```
class UpdateDateOnReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    add_column :reservations, :updated_date, :datetime
  end

end
```

If this does not answer your question, run your command with `--trace`, like: `be rake db:migrate --trace`, and post the results here or in a gist.